# Overlay div - scroll as much as content

Tags: jquery, css, html, overlay

I'm working on this site: http://www.massobservation.org. If you click on 'Information' a div is displayed on top of the content, an overlay if you will. However, I'd like the site, when the overlay is active, to only be scrollable as far as the content of the overlay div. You can see however, that even though the overlay ends (the yellow background ends) the site still scrolls to the bottom.

An example of this is given here: http://cargocollective.com/montessori

Any ideas? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the overlay is not a child element of `#top`, this should work:

When the overlay opens, add this style to your main content:

```
#top {
    position: fixed;
}
```

When the overlay closes, remove the style.

Comment: Grrr, I knew it had to be this simple! :)

Comment: I just used Firebug on the site you referenced to see how they were doing it. You're using [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) right?

Comment: Haha yep, but I just never thought to add it to the #top div... even though I must've played around with 80+ combinations. Now to get this jquery add class click function working. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

What you could try is:

- When the overlay is visible, set overflow: hidden; on the main content. I tried this on the div .work-section.
- Ensure the overlay content is NOT a child of the main content. Right now it's a child of the .work-section div, move it outside.

This should mean that only the overlay content causes the browser to scroll.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Adding overflow:hidden didn't work as well as I thought it would have - had some odd effects. I have moved the overlay div out of the main content.

Answer (score 0):

When showing the overlay, you can do something like:

a) Turn off scroll for main document - `$(document).css('overflow', 'hidden');`

b) Set height of overlay to window's height - `$(overlay).css('height', $(window).height()+'px');`

c) Set overflow: auto for overlay - `$(overlay).css('overflow', 'auto');`

That should ensure that scroll works only till the end of content in the overlay.